# Is there a way to make Tkinter text widget newline characters visible?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, newline, visible

I really would like to make Tkinter text widget newline characters visible when running under Python 3.4. It would be great if they appeared as a traditional Pilcrow (ASCII 20) character. If not, I suppose I could bind  to both the newline and Pilcrow character. Or globally search and replace newlines and replace them with a newline and a Pilcrow when the text file loads or changes, but then editing lines becomes a bit problematic. One might delete a Pilcrow but not the invisible newline character next to it, making things confusing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you simply replace `\n` with `¶\n` before displaying the text?

Comment: I thought of that, but since this is a text editor, the user might delete only the Pilcrow character (thinking he was deleting the return/newline) and then believe something was wrong because the next word in the line below the current wordwrap line doesn't move up. Still, I guess that would be the last resort.

Comment: Ah, editing is done in the text widget! Sorry. I'm afraid there's no easy solution then.

Comment: Rather than trying to re-engineer the text widget (a rather sobering thought) I'm simply going to globally replace \n with the Pilcrow and \n combination on loading the file (and stripping out the Pilcrows when saving the file) and bind the Pilcrow + \n  combination of characters to <Return>. I'll tell the user that the "real" \n is next to the Pilcrow and you must press the delete key again to actually eliminate the \n character, which should result in the first word on the next line moving up. (The window will have to be kept wider than the length of the lines of text.)

Comment: Are you sure this is worth it? This seems confusing.

Comment: Yes, well, I'd love to know how Notepad++ achieves the same thing. Probably does it from the Windows API somehow.

Comment: A text editor has many reasons to write its own text widget, this is one of them. Another would be using [a rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) to represent text.

Comment: Since it's free software, I looked up the code of Notepad++. First, it doesn't display pilcrows but CR and LF: it's an important distinction since depending on the platform where the file was created you won't [get the same combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations). Second, Notepad++ uses the [Scintilla text editing component](http://www.scintilla.org/index.html) which supports [`SCI_SETVIEWEOL`](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETVIEWEOL) to display all those EOL characters.